# How to create multiple route pages?

Tags: node.js, express

I got a folder named `routes`.

In my app.js I import it
`const routes = require('./routes');`

Instead of writing all logic for routes in index.js, I want the index.js to be main file for all routes. Can I achieve something like in js, where I import all routes here and export it?

I'd want my routes/index.js to look like:

```js
import user from "./user";
import files from "./files";

export default { 
  user,
  files
}
```

How can I do that in node way? Can someone write me a minimal example?

test.js

```js
const router = require('express').Router();

router
    .get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send("Test route")
    })

module.exports = router;
```

index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var test = require('./test');

app.use('/users', test);
```

Error message
`throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')`

Comment: that would work, have you tried it? if working with express you should export a router, then you can app.use the import

Comment: @LawrenceCherone do I need the index.js file then, if on every file I write `module.exports = router`?

Comment: try this `app.use("/api",require("./users/user.js"))` in index.js file then add your routes in a file called `user.js` and export Router from there.

Comment: In my app.js I already have `const routes = require('./routes');` `app.use(routes)`

Comment: no, though you could use one if you wanted, what I do is ./routes/module_name/index.js, then in that file if there is multiple sub routes like for example, ./routes/admin/[members, reports, settings, etc, etc] then they go in folders with an index.js, perhaps, item.js, something.js, they all export routers, IMO its easier to track, and keep to just crud for each endpoint all with class methods called, get,post,put,delete. vs having getUsers, putUser, fooBar methods.. note that `module.exports` is not the same as `export default`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, can you check my edited post? I added example how I do it. It says in docs thats the way to do it, for me it returns the error message.

Comment: your second example looks fine, though you kind of only want to load the routes from a single entrypoint, it prevents the server init code i.e src/index.js getting polluted with routes, here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-sound-18dbd you can do it many ways depends on your app, but just keep to if the route is `/users` then the controller is named `users`, not `test`, else your will get confused